# Can not load images with glide in recyclerview (data for recyclerview is fethced using retrofit)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, android-glide

My target is to fetch multiple image urls using an API and load those images in a 2d recyclerview. I'm using retrofit for fetching data and [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for displaying the images in the recyclerview.

Apparantly, there is no issue with fetching the urls. But no image is being loaded in the recyclerview and it isn't displaying any exception or warning either.

Here's how I've initialized the recyclerview: (**Class: HdrPhotoFragment.java**)

```java
        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
                new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), SPAN_COUNT)
        );
```

Here's what I've done in `onResponse()` for fetching the model and setting the adapter for recyclerview: (**Class: HdrPhotoFragment.java**)

```java
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<HdrPhotoListItemModel>> call, Response<List<HdrPhotoListItemModel>> response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.code());
                if (response.code() != 200) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: error fetching image data. CODE: ");
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error loading images", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                mHdrPhotoModelList = response.body();
//                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: response body" + response.body().toString());
                for (HdrPhotoListItemModel model : mHdrPhotoModelList) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Model = " + model.toString());
                }
                HdrPhotoListItemAdapter adapter = new HdrPhotoListItemAdapter(mHdrPhotoModelList, HdrPhotoFragment.this);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
```

And this is my `onBindViewHolder()` method where I've tried to load the image using glide: (**Class: HdrPhotoListItemAdapter.java**)

```java
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        HdrPhotoListItemModel itemModel = mHdrPhotoList.get(position);
//        holder.imageView.setImageResource(itemModel.getImageUrl());
        String url = Constants.BASE_URL + itemModel.getImageUrl();
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: URL: " + url);
        Glide.with(holder.imageView.getContext())
                .load(url)
                .into(holder.imageView);
    }
```

It is to be noted that the url obtained in `onBindViewHolder()` is accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly for what reason the image wasn't loading. Using [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) library instead of Glide solved this issue.

Inside `onBindViewHolder()` method, I just replaced

```java
        Glide.with(holder.imageView.getContext())
                .load(url)
                .into(holder.imageView);
```

whith the following line:

```java
        Picasso.get().load(url).into(holder.imageView);
```

Although it works, I would appreciate if anyone can tell me why it didn't work with Glide. My guess is that it has something to do with context.

Answer (score 1):

this should work
(code snippet in Kotlin)

```
Glide.with(holder.itemView.context).load(url).into(holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.image))
```

check the url also once